# How do I get the original destination IP of a redirected connection with pf on FreeBSD?

Tags: firewall, freebsd, nat

When I'm redirecting a connection with iptables on Linux with a `-j REDIRECT` rule, the program that receives the redirected connection can do `getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_IP, SO_ORIGINAL_DST, &val, &len);` to get the original, pre-redirection destination IP of the connection. How do I do the same thing when I'm redirecting a connection with pf on FreeBSD with an `rdr` rule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just solved this problem yesterday on MacOS, didn't test on FreeBSD, I think it's similar.

you need pfioc_natlook struct from `net/pfvar.h`.

General steps are:

- initialize `pfioc_natlook` to `pnl`
- fill pnl with client socket's ip & port(saddr,sxport), proxy server's bind ip & port(daddr, dxport)
- open('/dev/pf'), get its fd
- do ioctl(fd, C.DIOCNATLOOK, *pnl), then pnl's `rdxport` and `rdaddr` will be connection's original port & ip

Anyone still interested in this problem can check this gist: https://gist.github.com/gkoyuncu/f8aad43f66815dac7769

I did a mini POC program with golang(CGO wrapper), it works on MacOS: https://github.com/monsterxx03/pf_poc

Comment: How about UDP? Setting pfioc_natlook with proto set to IPPROTO_UDP doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The `net/pfvar.h` can be found within xnu kernel sources: https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu. For Big Sur look here:
https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-7195.121.3/bsd/net/pfvar.h